# DOSBox doesnt listen to resolution in config file

Tags: dosbox

I have DOSBox set to run at 640/480, but when I run it xwininfo says its running at 640x400 I've tried every option for "output:" and changing the resoultion to something weird like 64x480 keeps the same strange aspect ratio. Changing "aspect:" from false to true seems to have no effect either.

dosbox-0.74-conf:

```
[sdl]
fullscreen=false
fulldouble=false
fullresolution=1024x768
windowresolution=640x480
output=opengl
autolock=true
sensitivity=100
waitonerror=true
priority=higher,normal
mapperfile=mapper-0.74.map
usescancodes=true

[render]
frameskip=0
aspect=true
scaler=normal2x
```

EDIT: I'm running DOSBox 0.74 installed on Arch Linux via the `dosbox-debug` package in the AUR. Using the `dosbox` package in the normal repos doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by modifying the shortcut used to launch DOSBox. In the properties menu, there is the option to run program in true 640/480 mode. You may also have to dumb the compatibility mode down to Windows XP SP3.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Linux. I'll edit my post